# Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response. (storage/unknown)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

Im attempting to upload an Image to firebase storage.Im getting the error shown in the image.

[image]

Code:

```
uploadImage = async() => {
        
    const uri = await this.state.setSelectedImage;
    const childPath = `post/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/${Math.random.toString(36)}`
    console.log(childPath)

    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    
    const task = firebase.storage().ref().child(childPath).put(blob);

    const taskProgress = snapshot => {
        console.log(`transferred: ${snapshot.bytesTransferred}`)
    }
    
    const taskCompleted = () => {
        task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((snapshot) => {
            console.log(snapshot)
        })
    }

    const taskError = snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot)
    }

    task.on("state_changed", taskProgress, taskError, taskCompleted);



}
```